# Keyword search using AJAX in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, echo

I'm using AJAX and MySQL combination to search a database and display the results within the table. Unfortunately it won't echo the result from the database yet the code has found it.

```
$in=$_GET['txt'];
$msg="";
if(strlen($in)>0 and strlen($in) <20 ) {
    $t=mysql_query("SELECT user FROM users WHERE user LIKE '$in%'");
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($t)) {
        $msg.=$nt[name]."->$nt[id]<br>";
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

The issue seems to be in this part of my code.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selected `user` but you want to display `name` which the query is not returning so:

```
$in  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['txt']);
$msg = '';
if(strlen($in) > 0 && strlen($in) < 20){
  $t = mysql_query("SELECT id, name 
                    FROM users 
                    WHERE user 
                    LIKE '%$in%'");
  while($nt = mysql_fetch_array($t)){
    $msg .= $nt['name'] . "->" . $nt['id'] . "<br />";
  }
}

echo $msg;
```

Note that I've added `mysql_real_escape_string()` function for preventing mysql injection

Answer (score 1):

You select only `user` in your query. Should it be `*` instead?

```
SELECT user FROM users WHERE user LIKE '$in%'
->
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE '$in%'
```

Comment: In query strings is always better to write the name of the fields instead of *

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting `user` from database and concatenating `$msg` with `$nt[name]`

Your query should at least be

```
"SELECT user,name,id FROM users WHERE user LIKE '$in%'"
```